# Stop self hosted server from client

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have just started learning WCF. Currently i am working on a project where i am "self hosting" server on console application and the client is a WPF application.

**COntracts**

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IDemoValue
{
    [OperationContract]
    double IncrementByHundred(double val);
}
```

**Server**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using(ServiceHost host=new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfServiceDemos.DemoValue)))
        {
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Host is running at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}

</pre></code>
```

As from the code is clear that i am trying to Host WcfSericesDemos.DemoValue class.

**CLIENT**

//Event to start server (on button click)
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            object val1 = regKey.GetValue("SERVER");
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.FileName = val1.ToString();

try
        {
            using (Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                double inputValue = Convert.ToDouble(Input.Text);
                //Here IncrementByHundred(inputValue) is a method from DemoValue which iam trying to expose through WCF   
                OutPut.Content = server.IncrementByHundred(inputValue);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

Now my problem is Server is closing before the IncrementByHundred() method is Invoked.
So bottom line ,i want to stop the server from client side after IncrementByHundred() has finished its task.

**FYI:** I have tried working  Console.Readline() in the server,that does the job by server is still running ,but i want to close the server once IncrementByHundred() method has done its job.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "but i want to lose the server once IncrementByHundred() method has done its job." Why?!

Comment: @Aron sorry for the mistype its "Close"

Comment: Because i don`t want the server to run all the time just want it when it is required..

Comment: I think you misunderstood the meaning of server. Also... When do you know it is required?

Comment: @Aron As you can see from the code , the functionality of server is just to execute a method and return value..so i only require it when it is needed. i don`t want to run  it all the time consuming exta cpu resource..

Comment: Extra CPU resources? What resources do you think is being consumed by the server? The server should be just waiting for a request to come in, using zero (active) threads, a network port and an interrupt to spin up a thread WHEN a user request the execution of the method.